# Unity + Firebase - Unity.compat collision

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm encountering an issue with the **Unity.Compat.dll**.
This dll includes System.Reflection libraries in it.

If I want to use: **System.Reflection.TypeInfo**
For example, I cannot, because it will collide with the Unit.Compat.dll

This is the compilation error that I'm getting when trying to use TypeInfo:

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'TypeInfo' exists in both 'Unity.Compat, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Anyone else encountered with this issue?

Any workaround?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this issue?

Comment: There's no way to fix other than removing the duplicated declaration. (We can't, since it's in dll) Previously they have their own `Task` class which they use internally but that makes .NET 4.6 user couldn't use C#'s `Task`. That has been fixed, however there's more class like `Tuple` that is in `Unity.Compat`. They use it internally in their Firebase dll which is fine because .dll can't see outside world C#'s `Tuple`, but that makes the rest of the program can't use `Tuple` since we see 2 declarations of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll share the workaround that worked for me. Basically:

1. In player settings change **Scripting Runtime Version** from *'.Net 4.x  Equivalent'* to *'.Net 3.5 Equivalent'*
2. Restart Unity
3. Revert to 4.x
4. Restart again. Problem should be solved (at least it worked for me and a bunch of other people )

Unity 2018.1.4f1

source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/2w1Lk62VIcg/DbFGXg3-AQAJ

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Assets/Firebase folder from your project then re-importing the Firebase Unity SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem.

Firebase is colliding with the Entities package, among others.